# How to hide the apple push notification badge count, as soon as app installed?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have integrated push notification into iOS app. My problem is once I install the app, and reinstall it in another time, even before I login through the app my app icon shows the badge count. I dont want to show it if the user has logged out. So when user click on the logout I set the badge count as 0. But when I install it again, even before I log into it my app shows the notification badge count as a different number.

How can I avoide this? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: When else are you resetting?

Comment: I reset to 0 only when I log out from the app, when receive the notifications I set the badge count in appdelegate didfinishlaunch and remotenotificationdidreceived delegate

Comment: I guess you register notification before login. is it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more logic to your badge updates. In the app delegate, when the app is launched and / or you receive a notification you should check the user login status and update the badge number. If the user is not logged in then you can always simply set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

set badge 0 inside logout button action

```
-(void)logout{
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
  //.....
 }
```